# Which is the actual view i can see on my iphone?

Tags: iphone, view

How can a check which is the actual view i can see on my iphone?
thank you!

Comment: I think your question need to be explained more thoroughly. My first responce was going to be: "By looking at the iphone screen".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will do what you want, but see if the first view in the `view.subviews` array is the one that's on top. It sounds like you're doing things in a kind of unusual manner though.

Answer (score 0):

You could put something in that view and visually see what is displayed. I believe its pretty much same thing that Shynthriir was saying.

On the other hand, if you are competent with gdb you can set a breakpoint and poke around in the console

Comment: I got 3 uiviews and which lay over each other! And my actions change if my View which is in front change! So i Need to check which view is actually in front? Thank you for yor help!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just add some text like "View 1", "View 2" etc?